# Extract individual headshots from group photo

Tags: windows, osx, ios, photography, facial-recognition

I'm looking for a tool that will take a (high-resolution) group photo, locate all the faces automatically and extract them as individual headshots. Is there such a tool? Recognizing faces is pretty standard, but automatically extracting them as single files is something I haven't yet come across.

I wouldn't mind if the tool was free/cheap, either :)

Comment: which OS should it run on?

Comment: Oh right. Thanks for asking. I'd prefer Windows, but iOS or OS X would be fine, too.

Comment: If you have any scripting ability, on OSX you could use [FaceDetect](https://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/facedetect/) to extract coordinates which could then be passed to ImageMagick for extraction.

Comment: @StarGeek: Wow, that looks promising - it's a Python script, so it should work on Windows as well (where I feel more comfortable).

Comment: It takes a bit of work to make it usable on Windows.  Check [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/97cta2/looking_for_a_simple_face_detection_program_for/e4bsd4v/) I made which details the steps I had to go through to make it work.

Comment: @StarGeek: This worked perfectly - would you mind turning that into an answer (maybe even include the relevant parts of the reddit post)? To install opencv, the command `pip install opencv-python` worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @StarGeek ([relevant Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/software/comments/97cta2/looking_for_a_simple_face_detection_program_for/e4bsd4v/)), I was able to write a small script for this.

To get the environment set up in Python 3 (on a Windows 10 machine using Anaconda), I went through the following steps:

- `pip install opencv-python`
- Download and extract [`facedetect`](https://www.thregr.org/~wavexx/software/facedetect/)
- Rename `facedetect` to `facedetect.py`
- In the file `facedetect.py`, edit the line

`DATA_DIR = '/usr/share/opencv/'`

to the proper path. On my Windows 10 it was:

`DATA_DIR = 'C:/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/'`; if you have Python installed only for the current user, it might look something like

`DATA_DIR = '%LOCALAPPDATA%/Programs/Python/Python37/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/'`

- Finally, change the line

`'HAAR_FRONTALFACE_ALT2': 'haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml'`

to

`'HAAR_FRONTALFACE_ALT2': 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml',`

- Place the image(s) to be processed into the same directory as `facedetect.py`
- Run the following script in that directory:

```
import cv2
import facedetect
import glob
import os

facedetect.load_cascades(facedetect.DATA_DIR)

for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    original = cv2.imread(file)
    im, faces = facedetect.face_detect_file(file)
    if len(faces):
        directory = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(file)[1])[0]
        os.mkdir(directory)
        for i, (x,y,w,h) in enumerate(faces):
            face = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(directory, "{0:03}.jpg".format(i)), face)
```

For example, on this image (by Hayden Schiff (IagoQnsi, [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:FC_Cincinnati_starters_group_photo_(29125666664)_(cropped).jpg)))

[image: FC Cincinnati 2016]

the script produces the following output:

[image: Windows Explorer screenshot]

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer (you many have to wait until you can; use dot be 2 days, not sure now). Doing so will help others in future. if you really want to go over the top, you could find an image with a creative commons license and embed the image and the results in your answer, so that we get a feel for what it does.

Comment: @Mawg: Wonderful idea :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker Nicely done.  Sorry I didn't post as an answer, I felt that the answer should have included any scripting you actually did to extract the images.  Also, did you have to make changes to the facedetect script as I mentioned in the Reddit post or where you able to get it to run as is?

Comment: Please, do post such examples. Thanks++

Comment: @StarGeek: Ah, yes, I forgot that step. Will add that in momentarily.